# Label encoding by value counts

Tags: python, pandas, label-encoding

I try to do label encoding for my cities. However, I want it to label according to which city is more than others. Let's say;
Oslo has 500 rows
Berlin has 400 rows
Napoli has 300 rows in the dataset
So label encoding will label those cities according to value counts
so; Oslo should be labeled as 0, Berlin should be labeled 1, Napoli should labeled as 2

How I can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` with indices by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) (sorted values by default):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['Berlin'] * 4 + ['Oslo'] * 5 + ['Napoli'] * 3})
print (df)

s = df['col'].value_counts()
print (s)
Oslo      5
Berlin    4
Napoli    3
Name: col, dtype: int64

s1 = pd.Series(range(len(s)), index=s.index)
print (s1)
Oslo      0
Berlin    1
Napoli    2
dtype: int64
       
df['newcol'] = df['col'].map(s1)
print (df)
       col  newcol
0   Berlin       1
1   Berlin       1
2   Berlin       1
3   Berlin       1
4     Oslo       0
5     Oslo       0
6     Oslo       0
7     Oslo       0
8     Oslo       0
9   Napoli       2
10  Napoli       2
11  Napoli       2
```

Or use dictionary with `enumerate`:

```
s = df['col'].value_counts()
d = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(s.index)}
print (d)
{'Oslo': 0, 'Berlin': 1, 'Napoli': 2}      

df['newcol'] = df['col'].map(d)
print (df)
       col  newcol
0   Berlin       1
1   Berlin       1
2   Berlin       1
3   Berlin       1
4     Oslo       0
5     Oslo       0
6     Oslo       0
7     Oslo       0
8     Oslo       0
9   Napoli       2
10  Napoli       2
11  Napoli       2
```